# Why my SVG file is showing different in different browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, inkscape

I've created a SVG using Inkscape. Now, I've uploaded it to my page and it shows different in different browsers but I don't know what's the issue.

Firefox: The best render [image: Firefox render]
Chrome: Fails on the left side [image: Chrome render]

For at least, I want that Chrome render equals quality of Firefox render but I don't know how?

SVG File: https://github.com/AdrianArroyoCalle/adrianarroyocalle.github.io/blob/master/city.svg

Web: http://adrianarroyocalle.github.io

Also mention that if I open the SVG with Chrome without an HTML page, it shows like Firefox, but reduced.

Comment: Best if you create a reduced testcase with just the bit that goes wrong in it otherwise you're asking people to wade though an awful lot of markup.

Comment: Seems, that Chrome doesn't cut off outside the viewport. Have you tried `svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}` from [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css#L190-L192)?

Comment: Chrome doesn't support overflow: visible on outer `<svg>` elements yet. Firefox does.

Comment: Chrome 36+ (and Opera 23+) has support for `overflow: visible` on `svg` elements inline in html. Always mention which version you're testing in please. The website looked the same in Opera 25 and Firefox Nightly for me.

Comment: I've added viewBox attribute and it shows like Chrome on Firefox, but when I removed it. Firefox renders as the image here.